# Owl carousel : How to put navigation on image and not under?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, owl-carousel

I have a owl caroussel in my C# code. How can I place the nav buttons inside my img, like center and not under my image.

Comment: Can you explain your query in more specific way ?? I have used this plugin I may help you !!

Comment: I want the navigation buttons to be within the slides, not under image :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize the owl carousel in following method

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
            margin:10,
            responsiveClass:true,
            autoHeight:true,
            items:1,
            autoplay:true,
            autoplayTimeout:10000,
            autoplayHoverPause:true,
            nav : true,
            dots: true, //Make this true
            navText : ["<i class='fa fa-chevron-left'></i>","<i class='fa fa-chevron-right'></i>"]
        })
    });
```

Add CSS of the owl carousel control as following.(Change it accordingly)

```
.owl-controls {
position: relative;
top: -40px;
}
```

P.S. : If this is not your query or I might have not understood the query properly please comment it back.

**EDITS**

For previous button

```
.owl-prev {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30%;
    left: -50px;
}
```

For next button

```
.owl-next {
    position: absolute;
    right: -50px;
    top: 30%;
}
```

Comment: I have added this and now the buttons are on the image. How can i make the prev button on left and right button on right?

I think it is something with this, but where to add? 

`.owl-prev {`
`left: 0;`
}
.owl-next {
right: 0;
}

.owl-theme .owl-nav{margin-top:-10px; position: absolute; top: 40%;

Comment: This assumes that Font-Awesome - https://fontawesome.com/ - is installed, otherwise the <i class='fa fa-chevron-left'></i> icons will not show. Change: navText : ["<i class='fa fa-chevron-left'></i>","<i class='fa fa-chevron-right'></i>"] to: navText : ["<<",">>"] to see the icons without the Font-Awesome library.

Comment: Try change .owl-controls {
position: relative;
top: -40px;
} to .owl-nav {
position: relative;
top: -40%;
} - This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
            margin:10,
            responsiveClass:true,
            autoHeight:true,
            items:1,
            autoplay:true,
            autoplayTimeout:10000,
            autoplayHoverPause:true,
            nav : true,
            dots: false,
            navText : ["<i class='fa fa-chevron-left'></i>","<i class='fa fa-chevron-right'></i>"]
        })
    });
```

the navigation buttons appear under my slide with images. I want the buttons to be inside my image